# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function : While create dojo class

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am learning dojo

i have created a dojo class using declare as below

```
require(
["dojo/_base/declare"],function(declare){
    return declare(null,{
      constructor : function(){
          alert("done");
      }
    });
});
```

and this is save in /learnDojo/root/test.js
and the index.html as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dojoConfig = {
    async: false,
    parseOnLoad: false,
    isDebug : true,
    packages:[
        {   name:"base",
            location:"/learnDojo/root"
        }]
};
</script>
<script src="//localhost:8080/dojo1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
require(["base/test","dojo/_base/declare","dojo/domReady!"],function(test,declare){
    var test = new test();
});

</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

i have the index.html in the /learnDojo which is in webapps folder of the tomcat

When i load this from browser i am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function"

Why? any issue with code or dojo syntax for creating the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining Dojo modules you should be using `define()`, not `require()`. So your **/learnDojo/root/test.js** file would look like this:

```
define(
["dojo/_base/declare"],function(declare){
    return declare(null,{
      constructor : function(){
          alert("done");
      }
    });
});
```

The reason for this is that `define()` will actually return the object/value you returned in your callback (in this case the `return declare(...)` statement. A `require()` however will not return that value, causing strange errors.